# SQL Licensing on Azure, Standard D4 Windows 2012 Server 8 core, is it 1 phsysical core?

Tags: sql-server-2012, license, standard-edition

I am trying to calculate my costs for Microsoft Azure. Imagine I take a Standart D4 Type machine running Windows 2012 and would like to install my own SQL Server 2012.
Are these 8 cores 1 quad core with hyperthreading enabled, or are these 2 Quad cores without hyperthreading ? I mean do I have to pay only 1 or 2 core license for SQL 2012 Standart  Edition?

I could't fint the answer online. Neither I have the chance to create the machine now and check the socket number.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Use coreinfo from sysinternals. That will tell you the CPU, socket, hyperthreading, etc info.

Comment: yes i know I could as well use the task manager and see the sockets used, but I don't have the chance to create a machine.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to create the machine?  Presumably it would have been faster than searching the Internet and posting a question here...

Comment: Because i don't have a credit card to create an azure account...

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of stating the obvious, nothing is physical in Azure as far as you are concerned.  The best thing you can do is go to the [Azure Pricing Calculator](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines), find the 'SQL Server' section, select the 'Standard' section, find D-Series, select 'D4' and slide the slider to 1.  That's what you will be paying, eg

[image]

SQL Server will treat that box as having 8 cores, so should you.  You can also compare and contrast costs, eg try Enterprise edition.  As far as running coreinfo on Azure goes, don't bother unless you've got some time to kill.  By signing up to IaaS you have resolved to care much less about that kind of thing, freeing you up to concentrate on the software.

If you are concerned about performance you should cast your eye over this superb article:

**Performance Guidance for SQL Server in Azure Virtual Machines**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn248436.aspx

Comment: SQL server wont treat that box as having 8 cores. That's for sure. I know that I could as well use SQL Server on Azure, but I don't want to use SQL Azure, it's version 2014 + , since it already includes future features. I need 2012 and would like to ship my own version.